# Create a dummy by firm based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "var" : [3, 2, 1, 0.5, 5, 3, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 8, 5, 3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

I would like to create a dummy variable, for each individual firm, with the following condition:

'dummy' equals 1 whenever the variable 'var' is equal to or less than 0.5 for two consecutive years, so the variable 'dummy' looks like this:

```
data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "var" : [3, 2, 1, 0.5, 5, 3, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 8, 5, 3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], "dummy" : [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just shift, check for threshold and combine with the check on the original series:

```
df.groupby('firm')['var'].shift().le(.5) & df['var'].le(.5)
```

This should be slightly faster than `groupby().apply`.

Another approach, which is better in the case you need to check for several years, is `rolling`:

```
df['dummy'] = df.groupby('firm')['var'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(2).max().le(.5))
```

Output:

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16     True
17     True
Name: var, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `groupby` with `shift`

```
df.groupby('firm')['var'].apply(lambda x : x.shift().le(0.5) & x.le(0.5))
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16     True
17     True
Name: var, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements can be translated to pandas nearly litteraly.
First `groupby` firm, than check if your conditions are met with `apply`.
You can get the following year with `shift`

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"firm": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], "year" : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010], "var" : [3, 2, 1, 0.5, 5, 3, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 8, 5, 3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Solution
df['dummy'] = df.groupby('firm')['var'].apply(lambda x: (x.shift() <= .5) & (x <= .5)).view('i1')
print(df)
```

Out:

```
    firm  year  var  dummy
0      1  2000  3.0      0
1      1  2001  2.0      0
2      1  2002  1.0      0
3      1  2003  0.5      0
4      2  1990  5.0      0
5      2  1991  3.0      0
6      2  1992  2.0      0
7      2  1993  0.5      0
8      2  1994  0.5      1
9      3  2010  0.5      0
10     3  2011  0.0      1
11     3  2012  0.0      1
12     4  2005  8.0      0
13     4  2006  5.0      0
14     4  2007  3.0      0
15     4  2008  0.5      0
16     4  2009  0.5      1
17     4  2010  0.5      1
```